# identity server4 getting "invalid_grant" error for the connect/token endpoint when deployed to production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, identity

I use `Identityserver4` to implement `OAUTH2` and the server supports `ResourceOwnerPassword` and `code` flow. I use AWS's EC2 to host the app for production.

The weird thing is even the app runs perfectly fine in my dev machine, after deployed to AWS, I keep getting this `invalid_grant` and I do not know what goes wrong.

Here is my code:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            //.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddSigningCredential(Certificate.GetCertificate())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());

new Client
        {
         ClientId = "client",
         ClientName = "client",
         ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
         RequireClientSecret = false,
         RedirectUris = new List<string>(new string[] { "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback", "http://localhost:8002", "http://192.168.1.5:8002","app.buyingagent:/oauthredirect"}),
         AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
         //RequirePkce = true,
         AllowedScopes = { "api" },
         AllowOfflineAccess = true
        }

public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "cert", false);
            return certs.Count > 0 ? certs[0] : null;
        }
    }
```

I understand it is not a good practice to save the information in memory, but I just want to get the proof of concept first. For the `x509 certificate` which is passed to `AddSigningCredential` for signing token, I created a self-singing certificate in my local machine using `makecert` and then export it to the trusted store in AWS via `RDP`. (makecert does not seems avalible in AWS's command line)

I used this command: 
`makecert -pe -ss MY -$ individual -n "CN=cert" -len 2048 -r`

The app runs find locally but in production I keep getting this "invalid_grant" error. (I use `Postman` to get token)  I can visit the `connect/authorize` end point though(where I can enter client id and password)

The flow fails at `connect/authorize` end point.

The error message is like this:

```
POST http://{url}/connect/token
Request Headers:
    undefined:undefined
Request Body:
    grant_type:"authorization_code"
 code:"7cb58d345975af02332f2b67cb71958ba0a48c391e34edabd0d9dd1500e3f24e"
 redirect_uri:"https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
 client_id:"client"
Response Headers:
    undefined:undefined
Response Body:
    error:"invalid_grant"
    invalid_grant
Error
```

I know the entered info(client id, redirect url) are all correct(all working fine locally) what could go wrong here once deployed to production? Is the certificate not trusted in production or I cannot use in-memory storage for the client and resource? I do not think it is due to the `redirect_url` because even if I use the `password` flow which does not even require a `redirect_url` it still fails in production.

Note: if remove this line `AddSigningCredential(Certificate.GetCertificate())`(pass no certificate to identityserver4) I would get this same `"invalid_grant`. So maybe the certificate imported from my dev machine to AWS is invalid?

Comment: I am assuming that your comment `in production` means your code is running on a public server (AWS). This means that your need to use HTTPS, use a real SSL certificate for your domain (no self-signed) and you cannot use `localhost` for the `redirect_uri`. You will also need to specify the correct `redirect_uri` in your provider's console.

Comment: @JohnHanley But my certificate is for Identityserver4 to issue token, not for using the HTTPS. It is a x509 certificate not a SSL ceritifcate(If I understand it correctly) And when I use postman I dont think I need a real redirect_uri becasue it wont actually redirect to the specified url, the url is just for validating purpose(also my understanding only)

Comment: The redirect_uri is the callback for your tokens. Your invalid grant error is caused by the items that I mentioned that you need to correct.

Comment: I now use https with a ACM generated certificate and register a valid callback uri, but it is still not  working. I still use a self-signing key for the token validation purpose though. (I think it is OK to do that as shown in many identity server4 doc)http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/crypto.html#token-signing-and-validation

Comment: Using a self-signed certificate is OK for signing and validating your tokens. Q) Where is the client code running (on the same server or on a different computer)? The redirect_uri is where your tokens are passed to you. If the client is running on a different computer than you must use a URL that has a public dns address. Localhost only works when the client and OAuth server are running on the same machine.

Comment: The client is running on my dev machine and the identity server is running on AWS. I do not think the redirect_uri is really the problem in my case. I haved changed it to `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback` but it is still not working. Also, even if I use the "password" flow which does not require the redirect_uri , the identity server in AWS still fails while works perfectly in my dev machine.

Comment: Is `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback` your website?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186981/discussion-between-frostless-and-john-hanley).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After turning on the log,
the problem is `keyset does not exist`
The App has not permission to read the private key in the certificate. After adding the permission the problem is solved.
The initial `invalid_grant` is so misleading...

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem when I, in my infinite wisdom, set `accessToken` expiry time equal to `refreshToken` expiry, and asked for `refresh` only when `access` expired.