# Identity Server4 gives "invalid_grant" error when deployed to production, but works fine on localhost

Tags: c#, azure, localhost, identityserver4

My issue seems very similar to the following, but I'm unable to discern a solution that works.

[identity server4 getting "invalid_grant" error for the connect/token endpoint when deployed to production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261650/identity-server4-getting-invalid-grant-error-for-the-connect-token-endpoint-wh)

My code works fine on localhost, but as soon as I move to Azure I get:

'Invalid grant type for client: "authorization_code"'

...when reviewing a full set of Debug Errors the most relevant seems to be:

'Checking for PKCE parameters'

Is there something about the RedirectUri not being HTTPS? It would be a headache to have to issue genuine SSL Certs on every client machine, so that can't be right. Any chance someone is able to point me in the right direction? The previous SO thread seems to go "private" at a certain point and not really come back with a full solution.

The follow additional log elements maybe useful:

AuthorizeRequestValidationLog { ClientId: "desktopClient", ClientName: "Desktop", RedirectUri: "http://127.0.0.1:53508", AllowedRedirectUris: ["http://127.0.0.1:53508"], SubjectId: "anonymous", ResponseType: "code", ResponseMode: "query", GrantType: "authorization_code", RequestedScopes: "", State: "850ea39012d6cb9957943eec7e0d4940", UiLocales: null, Nonce: null, AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses: null, DisplayMode: null, PromptMode: null, MaxAge: null, LoginHint: null, SessionId: null, Raw: [("response_type": "code"), ("nonce": "cb71ec9cf7cd6ae6d4cad312f0a19769"), ("state": "850ea39012d6cb9957943eec7e0d4940"), ("code_challenge": "n-UyLEqkbUKjBFzP5-QQYjb5_l1G95pmtt6D_sqWUxE"), ("code_challenge_method": "S256"), ("client_id": "desktopClient"), ("scope": "openid profile api offline_access"), ("redirect_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:53508")] }

TokenIssuedFailureEvent { ClientId: "desktopClient", ClientName: "Desktop", RedirectUri: "http://127.0.0.1:53508", Endpoint: "Authorize", SubjectId: null, Scopes: "", GrantType: "authorization_code", Error: "unauthorized_client", ErrorDescription: "Invalid grant type for client", Category: "Token", Name: "Token Issued Failure", EventType: Failure, Id: 2001, Message: null, ActivityId: "80004ac4-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb", TimeStamp: 09/12/2021 17:53:13, ProcessId: 20916, LocalIpAddress: "10.0.0.4:443", RemoteIpAddress: "195.206.180.132" }

Please do let me know if my question needs more detail or rephrasing, this is my first time asking on SO, many thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Additional Information as suggested :)

WebAPI Code:

```
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthServer");
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "api";
                options.TokenRetriever = CustomTokenRetriever.FromHeaderAndQueryString;
            });
```

Auth Server Code:

```
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = false;
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.IssuerUri = Configuration["AuthServerUrl"];
            })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())

        builder.AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthDB"),
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthDB"),
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            });
```

Client in Config.cs:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "desktopClient",
    ClientName = "Desktop",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    ClientSecrets = {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 60 * 30, // 30 minutes
    AllowedScopes = {"openid profile api offline_access"},
    AllowedCorsOrigins =
    {
        "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net",
        "https://localhost:44323"
    },
    RedirectUris =
    {
        "http://127.0.0.1:53508/callback"
    },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris =
    {
        "http://127.0.0.1:53508/login"
    },
    RequireConsent = false
}
```

Identity Server SQL:

Clients:

```
9   True    desktopClient   oidc    False   FB  NULL    NULL    NULL    False   True    False   False   False   False   NULL    True    NULL    True    True    300 200 300 NULL    2592000 1296000 1   False   1   0   True    False   False   client_ NULL    14/04/2021 00:00:00 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    300 False
```

ClientGrantTypes:

```
9   authorization_code  9
```

Desktop Client Code:

```
static string _authority = Settings.Current.ServerAuth.URL;
static string _baseAPIaddress = Settings.Current.ServerAPI.URL;
static string redirectUri = "http://127.0.0.1:53508";
static string _clientid = "desktopClient";
static string _scope = "openid profile api offline_access";


        var options = new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = _authority,
            ClientId = _clientid,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = _scope,
            FilterClaims = false,
            Browser = browser,
            Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.AuthorizationCode,
            ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect
        };
        _oidcClient = new OidcClient(options);
```

Error Log:

```
Start authorize request
No user present in authorize request
Start authorize request protocol validation
desktopClient found in database: True
client configuration validation for client "desktopClient" succeeded.
Checking for PKCE parameters
AuthorizeRequestValidationLog { ClientId: "desktopClient", ClientName: "Desktop", RedirectUri: "http://127.0.0.1:53508", AllowedRedirectUris: ["http://127.0.0.1:53508"], SubjectId: "anonymous", ResponseType: "code", ResponseMode: "query", GrantType: "authorization_code", RequestedScopes: "", State: "850ea39012d6cb9957943eec7e0d4940", UiLocales: null, Nonce: null, AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses: null, DisplayMode: null, PromptMode: null, MaxAge: null, LoginHint: null, SessionId: null, Raw: [("response_type": "code"), ("nonce": "cb71ec9cf7cd6ae6d4cad312f0a19769"), ("state": "850ea39012d6cb9957943eec7e0d4940"), ("code_challenge": "n-UyLEqkbUKjBFzP5-QQYjb5_l1G95pmtt6D_sqWUxE"), ("code_challenge_method": "S256"), ("client_id": "desktopClient"), ("scope": "openid profile api offline_access"), ("redirect_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:53508")] }
Invalid grant type for client: "authorization_code"
Request validation failed
AuthorizeRequestValidationLog { ClientId: "desktopClient", ClientName: "Desktop", RedirectUri: "http://127.0.0.1:53508", AllowedRedirectUris: ["http://127.0.0.1:53508"], SubjectId: "anonymous", ResponseType: "code", ResponseMode: "query", GrantType: "authorization_code", RequestedScopes: "", State: "850ea39012d6cb9957943eec7e0d4940", UiLocales: null, Nonce: null, AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses: null, DisplayMode: null, PromptMode: null, MaxAge: null, LoginHint: null, SessionId: null, Raw: [("response_type": "code"), ("nonce": "cb71ec9cf7cd6ae6d4cad312f0a19769"), ("state": "850ea39012d6cb9957943eec7e0d4940"), ("code_challenge": "n-UyLEqkbUKjBFzP5-QQYjb5_l1G95pmtt6D_sqWUxE"), ("code_challenge_method": "S256"), ("client_id": "desktopClient"), ("scope": "openid profile api offline_access"), ("redirect_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:53508")] }
TokenIssuedFailureEvent { ClientId: "desktopClient", ClientName: "Desktop", RedirectUri: "http://127.0.0.1:53508", Endpoint: "Authorize", SubjectId: null, Scopes: "", GrantType: "authorization_code", Error: "unauthorized_client", ErrorDescription: "Invalid grant type for client", Category: "Token", Name: "Token Issued Failure", EventType: Failure, Id: 2001, Message: null, ActivityId: "80004ac4-0000-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb", TimeStamp: 09/12/2021 17:53:13, ProcessId: 20916, LocalIpAddress: "10.0.0.4:443", RemoteIpAddress: "195.206.180.132" }
Request finished in 810.6797ms 302
```

Comment: perhaps post a sample client definition and your AddOpenIDConnect code from your startup class?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I hope I've shared the right code snippets, thank you for your thoughts :)

Comment: how is your AllowedGrantTypes in the client definition defined? should be GrantType.Code?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't added enough of my code to the Auth Code section above. Its using config from SQL: '.AddConfigurationStore' and '.AddOperationalStore', which I understand uses the table ClientGrantTypes to determine the GrantType, and the ClientID associated with the desktopClient has been give the GrantType "authorization_code". Maybe I've miss understood something there?

Comment: As a side note, you should try to use HTTPS for both the client applications and IdentityServer, becasue the cookies issued by both of them have the samesite=none attribute set and for browsers to accept that cookie, it needs to be sent over HTTPS

Comment: @ToreNestenius I reached a similar conclusion that it must be HTTPS vs HTTP related rather than anything else since it works fine locally I assume the Identity Server 4 config "should" be okay. I'm using one of their samples as the basis for the Client Authentication and have extended https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/NetCoreConsoleClient/src/NetCoreConsoleClient to work in a WinForms Application as my Desktop Client, but its using http for the Loopback Listener. I'm not sure where to begin making that listen on https instead.

Comment: Does the HTTPS imperative stay true for Desktop Apps where I'm not using a browser beyond the initial sign in to get the 'authorization_code'?
It seems like an internal error from IS4. Does that mean I've got something configured wrong in Production? I can't see any difference there compared to localhost which also running over HTTPS, though I assume localhost is more trusted on some level.

Comment: Cookies, especially the session cookies set by identityserver is set using SameSite=None and this must be set over HTTPS, otherwise modern browsers will/may reject them. Exactly what error do you get at this point?  Are you sure its not a PKCE error?

Comment: The server side error log is added above. It mentions PKCE, but doesn't suggest any related errors. Does the localhost version use PKCE too? It doesn't look like the OidcClientOptions include PKCE, but I've not got it set to "required" on the Identity Server side either. All rather confusing...

Comment: are you sure the desktopClient client defintinion in IdentityServer do allow authorization_code? This needs to be explicitly defined per client in IdentityServer.

Comment: Do I have to define Clients in my Config.cs and in the Database? So far it was only in the Database with "authorization_code" in GrantTypes. I've now hard coded it into the Config.cs as added above, but I still get the same error.